# UIScrollView won't scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have tried the following:

```
contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 400)];
[contentScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 400)];
[contentScrollView addSubview:twitterSigninViewController.view];
[contentScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

However, this doesn't scroll. Why is this?

Comment: Did you add `contentScrollView` to the window or current view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't scroll because there's nothing to scroll. You told it your content size was exactly the same size as the scrollview itself, so it's already displaying everything. You can set the `alwaysBounceHorizontal` or `alwaysBounceVertical` properties if you want it to always bounce when trying to scroll, but that's about it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the frame size (how large the actual view is) is the same as your content size (how large your content is).  So if you make your frame's height less than your contentSize's height it will scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer to your question change `setContentSize:` line to:

```
[contentScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600.0, 481.0)];
```